# How to store YMD, HM but not S Seconds in mariaDB/MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, datatypes, datetime

I was trying to make a column that stores the showtime of movies.

Since it is more meaningful to have showtimes in the unit of minutes, can I have a date type that has only years to minutes (eg. `2017-12-26 15:30`), but no seconds? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special datatype for this :) Instead, you can use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

## Example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```

So you can create a view to converting your datetime column to the specific date format.

## Create table with Datetime

```
create table test (date datetime);
insert into test values (now());
select * from test;
2017-12-28 10:30:24
```

## Create view to convert date format

```
create view v_test as (select DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'));

select * from v_test;
2017-12-28 10:30
```

Comment: So is it okay if I just do `DATA_FORMAT()` and *ignore* the `%s` completely?

Comment: Yeah, its enough.

Comment: Okay. One more thing... What about storing HH and MM as deprecate integers (to save the unnecessary space for seconds)?

Comment: See, your data in already stored in the table, there is no straight forward method to store the data as you like. So we created views, no need for additional storage for this.

Comment: I found this method cannot be used in a generated column in the same table without modification. What tweaks should be made to have this in a generated column in the same table? Thanks!

Comment: @jackxujh - Using a `VARCHAR` for "2017-12-28 10:30" takes 10 bytes; a `DATETIME` takes 5.  Also, it is usually best to us the database as a data store, and use the app as a formatting tool.

Comment: @RickJames Oh cool! Yeah, using the app to format is yet another good way!